# If $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda(A)>0$ then A has infite elements

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that if $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda(A)>0$ then A has infite elements

If $A=\emptyset$ or $A=\{a\}$ then it is clear that $\lambda(\{a\})=a-a=0$

But for $A=(a,b)$ for b>a I am not sure how to show this. Of course $(a,b) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncoutable.

But is there some easier way to show this? I want to avoid a big (Cantor) proof to show that (a,b) is uncountable

Comment: This is very easy with the contrapositive: If $A$ has finitely many elements, then $\lambda(A)=0$.

Comment: It applies even if it had *countably* many elements, proving also that $\lambda(A)>0$ implies $A$ is uncountable.